# Count rows from a query

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT msg 
FROM msgs 
WHERE topic='$topic' 
ORDER BY likes_a ASC
```

I need to count how many rows are there `WHERE topic='$topic'`

How do I count this?

Comment: Add the `COUNT()` function and remove the `ORDER BY` clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: @Maximus2012 thanks, working.

Comment: or u can do it in php way like 
`$result = $mysqli->query("your query here")
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;`

Comment: SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM msgs 
WHERE topic='$topic' 
ORDER BY likes_a ASC

Answer (score 4):

When you are tell the query to `SELECT msg`, you are telling it to select all of the messages that meet your criteria and return them. When you change it to `SELECT COUNT(msg)`, you are only asking for the number of msg that meet your criteria.

```
SELECT COUNT(msg) 
FROM msgs 
WHERE topic='$topic'
```

Comment: You don't need `ORDER BY` clause if you are using `COUNT` like this.

Comment: Thank you, @Maximus2012, I had actually caught that and was editing it as you wrote the comment.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to write the following query without `order by`

```
SELECT COUNT(msg) FROM msgs WHERE topic='$topic';
```

It's a plane SQL query and will work on MySQL, MS SQL server etc with having any issue.